# vb.net how to check if a string has a certain word

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

i want to check if a string matches a word in array not just matches characters. the contains method just checks the matches characters not the whole word. here is my code:

```
 Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
    Dim reader As New StringReader(txtOCR.Text)
    Dim titles() As String = {"the", "a", "an", "of"}
    Dim regex As New Regex(String.Join("|", titles), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    While True
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        If line Is Nothing Then Exit While
        Dim WordCount = New Regex("\w+").Matches(line).Count

        If WordCount = 1 And Not line.ToLower().Contains("by") Then
            builder.AppendLine(line)
        ElseIf regex.IsMatch(line) Then
            builder.AppendLine(line)
        End If

    End While
    txtTitle.Text = builder.ToString()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use word boundaries `\b` to surround the individual words:

```
New Regex("\b" & String.Join("\b|\b", titles) & "\b")
```